# `SQL Results` tabs of Eclipse -- `Status` and `Result1`

Tags: sql, eclipse

Whenever an SQL query has results to show, `SQL Results` tab of Eclipse opens a `Result1` tab right next to the `Status` tab in it and shows the results there.

However, it is returning the control to the `Status` tab, i.e. showing 
`Status` and not `Result1` once the query is done.

How/where on Eclipse can this be turned around so that the first result tab (whenever there are results and thus such a tab out of the query) instead of the `Status`
tab will show?

This would relieve me off of clicking the result tab after each and every such query.

TIA.

Comment: Depending on what kind mistakes one makes in their query,  there might not be a `Result` tab at all.  `Status`, however, always applies..

Comment: @PM "Whenever an SQL query has.. ". read the Q.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Results' preferences, changing to 'Single Window' under 'Display Window' (from 'Multiple Windows') worked for me.

See also eclipse [documentation](https://help.eclipse.org/luna/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.datatools.sqltools.doc.user%2Fdoc%2Fhtml%2Fasc1229700412058.html).

> Single Window — display execution results in a single window, with
>   status details at the end. For a single statement with multiple
>   results, display result sets one after another in the same window.

Comment: Please include the essential parts of the link content in the answer